# Zend Framework: isValid() clears values from disabled form fields!

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

When you submit a form, disabled form fields are not submitted in the request.

So if your form has a disabled form field, it makes working with `Zend_Form::isValid()` a little frustrating.

```
$form->populate($originalData);
$form->my_text_field->disabled = 'disabled';
if (!$form->isValid($_POST)) {
    //form is not valid
    //since my_text_field is disabled, it doesn't get submitted in the request
    //isValid() will clear the disabled field value, so now we have to re-populate the field
    $form->my_text_field->value($originalData['my_text_field']);
    $this->view->form = $form;
    return;
}

// if the form is valid, and we call $form->getValues() to save the data, our disabled field value has been cleared!
```

Without having to re-populate the form, and create duplicate lines of code, what is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: It's not really up to Zend Form; the HTML spec says that disabled elements don't get submitted, while readonly elements do (which explains @robertbasic's suggestion below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you setting the element to disabled so that the user can't edit it's contents but only to see it? If so, just set the element's readonly attribute to true, I think it'll work that way.

Comment: I had the same problem, and this worked.  Like robertbasic says, just set the 'readonly' attribute instead of the 'disabled' attribute.

Comment: Readonly gets submitted, disabled doesn't, as per the spec; see the [WC3's Forms in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) for details, particularly the bits on "disabled", "readonly" and ["successful"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls) - readonly can be successful, while disabled cannot (and is therefore not submitted).

Answer (score 1):

I use a custom class inherited from Zend_Form. Class adds some features and solves this problem by replacing the method isValid as follows:

```
class Murdej_Form extends Zend_Form {
    function isValid($data) {
        $_data = $this->getValues();
        $valid = parent::isValid($data);
        $this->populate($_data);
        return $valid;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `isValid()` we can use `isValidPartial()`. Unlike `isValid()`, however, if a particular key is not present, it will not run validations for that particular element. So, `isValidPartial()` will not validate for disabled fields.

Reference: [ZF Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html#zend.form.quickstart.validate)

Comment: The only problem with this is if a required field was not submitted in the form, it won't be validated.